# PHP: How to use str_replace?

Tags: php

My server has been hit with a nasty javascript iframe virus. The Trojan injects itself in to every index.php, index.html, & login.php files. The virus looks like `<script>VirusCodeCrap</script>`

Is there anyway I could use PHP's str_replace function to search my server and delete the virus? Would anyone know wher I could find some examples on how to do this?

Thanks,

Albert

Comment: Sorry, I had javascript symbols around VirusCodeCrap, but they were taken out on post.

Comment: Your question is not well titled - `str_replace` may not be a solution at all if the code inside the tags varies. Why not name it "how to search & replace virus from many files" or something?

Comment: You need to remove virus itself rather than fixing your files at this time.

Comment: Yes, you can (with a regex expression, not `str_replace`), but you'll need to deal with the security breach as well, otherwise you'll end up cleaning everything again sooner or later.

Comment: Contact your host **now**.  Not tomorrow, not in a few hours, **now**.  They need to know so that they can isolate your environment and try to prevent any attacks from spreading to other customers...

Comment: Sorry for the terrible title. I did contact Dreamhost, TMDhosting, & Godaddy but they offer no assistance. They said because I am using opensource software that it's my problem and not theirs.

Comment: @Albert: Wow.  That's one heck of a response.  I agree that it's not their job to fix it, but it's their responsibility to investigate and maintain the security for the rest of their customers.  Otherwise it could be seen as a huge act of neglagence...

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Unix server, `sed` is the best way to find and replace text in files.

If you must use PHP, the algorithm will be:

1. Read a file into a variable using [`file_get_contents()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.file-get-contents.php)

   `$file_contents = file_get_contents( $filename );`
2. Search for the replace the offending string

   `$file_contents = str_replace( $the_offending_text, $the_replacement_text, $file_contents);`
3. Write `$file_contents` back to the file using [`file_put_contents`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.file-put-contents.php):

   `file_put_contents( $file_contents );`

`str_replace()` may be insufficient if the string is not precisely the same in every case. If there are variations in the offending string, you may need to use a regular expression to locate and remove them.

Answer (score 0):

I would immediately delete all files from your server and re-upload clean copies from wherever your code repository is. I would also find where the code was exploited and patch that security hole.

Going about it by editing the virus out of your files seems like the long and hard way when you should have a backup of your files ( that haven't been on a live server ).